# mechanize, urllib, beautifulsoup & relative paths

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup, mechanize, urllib2

Does mechanize, urllib or beautifulsoup have any built in methods for handling crawling of  websites with a mixture of absolute and relative urls?

A solution is lots of exceptions

```
'http://' + 'www.stackoverflow.com'
'http://www.stackoverflow.com' + '/questions/ask'
```

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this was my solution :)

```
domain = re.search('(http:\/\/.*\.\D+?|https:\/\/.*\.\D+?)\/',url.strip()).group(1)

if re.search('mailto',url.strip()) != None:
    pass
elif re.search('(http:\/\/.*\.\D+?|https:\/\/.*\.\D+?)\/',url.strip()) != None:
    u = url.strip().encode('utf8')
elif re.search('^/',url.strip()) != None:
    u = domain+url.strip().encode('utf8')
else:
    u = domain+'/'+url.strip().encode('utf8')
```